# How to train model with two kids functions for object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I'm trying to implement the model described by Professor Andrew Ng for [object detection](https://youtu.be/cz-ttO-cKNk) (explanation starts at 10:00).

He describes the first element of the output vector as the probability that an object was detected, followed by the coordinates of the bounding box of the object matched (when one is matched). The last part of the output vector is a softmax of all the classes your model knows.

As he explains it, using a simple squared error for the case when there is a detection is fine, and just the squares difference of `y^[0] - y[0]`. I get that this is a naive approach. I'm just wanting to implement this for the learning experience.

## My questions

1. How do I implement this conditional loss in tensorflow?
2. How do I handle this conditional about `y^[0]` when dealing with a batch.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I implement this conditional loss in tensorflow?

You can convert the loss function to:

```py
Error = mask[0]*(y^[0]-y[0])**2 + mask[1]*(y^[1]-y[1])**2 ... mask[n]*(y^[n]-y[n])**2),
where mask = [1, 1,...1] for y[0] = 1 and [1, 0, ...0] for y[0] = 0
```

> How do I handle this conditional about y^[0] when dealing with a
>   batch.

For a batch, you can construct the mask on the fly like:

```py
mask = tf.concat([tf.ones((tf.shape(y)[0],1)),y[:,0][...,None]*y[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

Code:

```py
y_hat_n = np.array([[3, 3, 3, 3], [3,3,3,3]])
y_1 = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1,1,1,1]])
y_0 = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1], [0,1,1,1]])


y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4])
y_hat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 4])
mask = tf.concat([tf.ones((tf.shape(y)[0],1)),y[:,0][...,None]*y[:,1:]], axis=1)

error = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(mask*y, mask*y_hat)

with tf.Session() as sess:

   print(sess.run([mask,error], {y:y_0, y_hat:y_hat_n}))
   print(sess.run([mask,error], {y:y_1, y_hat:y_hat_n}))

# Mask and error
#[array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
#   [1., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), 2.25]

#[array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
#   [1., 1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32), 4.0]
```